# syntax error running React app on IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, browserify

I get a syntax error on "class ProductList extends React.Component {" when i run my app in IE. In chrome it works good but in IE none of the react seems to work and i get an syntax error on the first react row. 
Am i missing something obvious? A package of some kind?

```
   var React = require('react');
   var PamService = require('../service/pamService');

   class ProductList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({
        products: [],
        filteredProducts: []
    });
    this.getProducts();
}
getProducts() {
    var state = this;
    PamService.getProducts("IDDS_stefan", "en").then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        var products = state.setNoImage(result.data);
        state.setState({
            products: products,
            filteredProducts: products
        });
    });
}
setNoImage(products) {
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].Image === "") {
            products[i].Image =  "test";
        }
    }
    return products;
}
filterProducts(categoryId) {
    console.log("FILTERPRODUCSSMAFFAKKA");
    var products = this.state.products;
    var filteredProducts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].CategoryId.toLowerCase() === categoryId.toLowerCase()) {
            filteredProducts.push(products[i]);
        }
    }
    this.setState({ filteredProducts: filteredProducts });
}
searchProducts(searchText) {
    var filteredProducts = this.state.products;
    var searchedProducts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredProducts.length; i++) {
        if (filteredProducts[i].Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
            searchedProducts.push(filteredProducts[i]);
        } else if (filteredProducts[i].ShortDescription.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
            searchedProducts.push(filteredProducts[i]);
        } else if (filteredProducts[i].ProductId.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
            searchedProducts.push(filteredProducts[i]);
        }
    }
    this.setState({ filteredProducts: searchedProducts });
}
resetProducts() {
    var products = this.state.products;
    this.setState({
        filteredProducts: products
    });
}
render() {
    return (<div className="product-container">
                    <div className="product-list" >
                        <div className="product-list-header">
                            <div>&nbsp;</div>
                            <div>Art.No</div>
                            <div>Name</div>
                            <div>Description</div>
                            <div>Unit</div>
                            <div>Remark</div>
                            <div>Info</div>
                            <div>Stock</div>
                            <div>Price (EUR)</div>
                            <div>Quantity</div>
                            <div id="refresh-product-list" onClick={() => this.resetProducts()}>
                                <i className="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {
                        this.state.filteredProducts.map((product) => {
                            return <div className="product-list-item" key={product.ProductId}>
                                <div>
                                    <img src={'data:image/png;base64,' + product.Image} className="product-image"></img>
                                </div>
                                <div>{product.ProductId}</div>
                                <div>{product.Name}</div>
                                <div>{product.ShortDescription} </div>
                                <div>Needed?</div>
                                <div>Needed?</div>
                                <div>Needed?</div>
                                <div>Where to get?</div>
                                <div>1</div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>)
}
};

 module.exports = ProductList;
```

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: Edge, but any of them gives the same result

Comment: Insufficient information to work with. Can you create a fiddle or something for us to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using babel to transpile your es6 code? Check out create-react-app for examples https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app.

Answer (score 0):

remember that chrome and firefox will support most of the features of ES6 or the javascript revision that it appears there. However Edge and IE do not support such features. In order for you to run Javascript ES6 in those browser you need to convert or transpile that code to native javascript.. for that you can use babel which is a great helper for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

In head of index.html to tell IE run compatible mode